# Need MySQL query to fetch alternate records from database

Tags: mysql

I have two tables **A** and **B**. My query is-

```
Select A.item, B.description, B.brand from A inner Join B on A.id=B.a_id where B.brand_id=1 limit 0,3
UNION
Select A.item, B.description, B.brand from A inner Join B on A.id=B.a_id where B.brand_id=2 limit 0,3
UNION
Select A.item, B.description, B.brand from A inner Join B on A.id=B.a_id where B.brand_id=3 limit 0,3
```

And output is similar to-

```
item    description    brand
1001    item1          brand1
1002    item2          brand1
1003    item3          brand1
1004    item4          brand2
1005    item5          brand2
1006    item6          brand2
1007    item7          brand3
1008    item8          brand3
1009    item9          brand3
```

Now my requirement is to fetch record as-

```
item    description    brand
1001    item1          brand1
1004    item4          brand2
1007    item7          brand3
1002    item2          brand1
1005    item5          brand2
1008    item8          brand3
1003    item3          brand1
1006    item6          brand2
1009    item9          brand3
```

any suggestion :(

Comment: So what you ultimately want is the set of 3 from each brand interleaved?

Comment: yes Michael you are right and sorry if I am not clear enough..

Comment: What application programming language are you using? Probably I would fetch all the rows you have into a single array (or whatever structure your language prefers) and then modify the order of the array.  To be clear, I would only do this on a small rowset. If your production rowset is much larger than this, then chopping up the output in code may not be most efficient.

Comment: Please post table structure and sample data

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: my app is in PHP and I am fetching over 1,000 records.

Comment: @santosh how many columns per record? Is it just the three you have above?  Another option is to perform 3 queries rather than a `UNION` and fetch from all 3 at once to produce your output. That may be more efficient than fetching all from the `UNION` and hacking/re-sorting the one array.

Comment: @Michael: I am fetching 11 columns per record from 7 tables and the problem is, I am not sure how many brand I have to look for. I am generating my query dynamically in the PHP script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a pure SQL answer then the following MySQL workaround for Oracle's [RANK OVER PARTITION](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions.php#rank) coupled with an inline view and some ordering should work however many brands you have:

```
select item,description,brand
from
(select A.item, B.description, B.brand,
case B.brand
        when @curBrand 
        then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        else @curRow := 1 and @curBrand := B.brand END
      as rank
from A inner join B on A.id=B.a_id
join (select @curRow := 0, @curBrand := '') r
) t
order by t.rank,t.brand;
```

Enjoy!

Comment: can I have MySQL version of your query. It's going over my head :(

Comment: this is a MySQL version of the query! Give it a go in MySQL. It is not an Oracle query just a MySQL version of an Oracle function....